# C++ List Iterator cant be initlaized

Tags: c++, list, compiler-errors, iterator, constants

I have two functions in my Character class:

```
void Character::dropItem(const Item & item)
{
    for (list<const Item*>::iterator i = playerInventory.inventory.begin(); i != playerInventory.inventory.end(); i++) {
        if ((*i) == &item) {
            playerInventory.inventory.erase(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}

double Character::getTotalWeight() const
{
    for (list<const Item*>::iterator i = playerInventory.inventory.begin(); i != playerInventory.inventory.end(); i++) {

    }
}
```

However, Visual Studio gives me an error

```
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>' to 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>'
```

on playerInventory in the first statement of the for loop in getTotalWeight().
I can't figure out why this error is occurring, because it's literally the same loop as the function just above it. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: You want `const_iterator` instead of `iterator`, or use `auto`

Comment: Assuming you have C++11 or better available, `auto` is a lot easier than `std::list<const Item*>::const_iterator`.

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory.  A `iterator` and a `const_iterator` are different types, and an `iterator` can't be used on a `const` container (since it provides a means to change elements).      Either remove the `const` qualifier from the function, or use `const_iterator` rather than `iterator`.   Or  (C++11 and later) use `auto` (which will, in effect, pick the iterator based on whether the container is `const`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is a constant member function

```
double Character::getTotalWeight() const
```

So the data member `playerInventory.inventory` is considered as a constant data member. As a result you may not use a non-constant iterator.

Write instead

```
for (list<const Item*>::const_iterator i = playerInventory.inventory.cbegin(); i != playerInventory.inventory.cend(); i++) {
```

That is the member function `begin` returna `const_iterator` while you are trying to assign it to `iterator` and there is no corresponding conversion from the first iterator type to the second iterator type.